# "Access violation reading location 0x0000000c" error

Tags: c++

Code fragments:

-inserting instances into object manager

```
Object* o;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
{
    o = new Tile(32*i, 0);
    o->ID = i+2;
    o_manager.Create(i+2,o);
}
o = new Player(50.,50.);
o->ID = 1;
o_manager.Create(1,o);
```

-inserting instances from manager into quadtree

```
CollisionDetector = new QuadTree(0, bounds);
for(std::map<unsigned int, Object*>::iterator it = Instances.begin(); it !=  Instances.end(); it++)
{
  std::cout << it->second->COL << std::endl;
  if(it->second->COL) //probable place of error
  {
     std::cout << "Object (" << it->first << ")... ";
     CollisionDetector->insert(it->second);
  }
  std::cout << "inserted into QuadTree" << std::endl;
}
```

I've got a problem, which cause is completly unknown for me. I've got an object manager class in which I put 11 instances (into map container). Then every step it would pass instances with collision flag set to the quadtree list.

After executing I receive an error: **"Access violation reading location 0x0000000c"**.

From what I get from stdout, **error shows up while inserting 11-th instance into the quadtree (stdout prints flag value, but doesn't print "Object (ID)..."). When I reduce number of instances to 10 orless everything works fine**.

I'd be grateful for any advices, because I have no idea where to find solution.
Sorry for my english, I'm not native speaker.

Comment: If you haven't done it before, this is a good time to learn how to use a debugger. If you run your program in a debugger, it will stop at the location of the crash, you will be able to see the function call stack, and go up to your code (if not already there), and examine the contents of variables.

Comment: It may be helpful to see the Create function.

Comment: I guess you're right. Currently I don't understand anything what is written there.

Here's Create definition:
`void ObjectManager::Create(unsigned int id, Object *o)`
 {
  Instances.insert(std::pair<unsigned int, Object *>(id, o));
 }

Answer (score 1):

"I've got an object manager class in which I put 11 instances (into map container)."

But that's just 10 instances:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, you should post more code.

Comment: The Player is also (presumably) put into the map, right after the loop, though.

Comment: Look little lower, I add player instance. That's 11th

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is for sure a pointer that is null. The `0x0000000c` is the address of a member relatively to the start address of an object. (probably `COL`, if you give us the header for `Object`)

Make sure the elements you add to the map are not null.

Comment: I would guess and say it->second is null at the line indicated by "probable place of error"

Comment: Yes so would I too... That is why I suspect a null pointer is added to the map.

Comment: I was aware of that, so I put line above to print COL value in order to check this. But correct value is printed and I think pointer can't change on it's own adress it's pointing at.